LWC getRecord return difference
When I use getRecord in LWC, the result below is different.
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [SOME_IMPORT_FIELD] })
recordData1;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: [SOME_IMPORT_FIELD] })
recordData2({error, data}){
    if(error) ...
    else if(data) ...
}

Then, write
console.log('recordData1', recordData1)
console.log('recordData2', recordData2)

in connectedCallback, result in console is like:
recordData1 ( data : undefined, error : undefined)
recordData2 { Some data what I excpected, no error...}

Why is this happen?

As per the documentation:

Wire adapter calls are asynchronous unless data is cached. Therefore,
the order of response and promise resolution are not sequential.

In your code recordData1 is a property and recordData2 is a function.
The recordData1 will automatically be populated with the data or error once the wire service fetches the record. This happens asynchronously, and the initial value of recordData1 is { data: undefined, error: undefined } until the data is fetched. After the wire service fetches the data, the property will update.
When the wire decorator is used with a function, the framework invokes the function immediately when there is new data or an error. This provides you with the fetched data or the error directly in the function parameters, even during the initial phase.
The difference is that property-based wiring holds a static reference that gets updated asynchronously when the wire service completes and function-based wiring allows immediate execution of the provided function whenever there is a change in the data or error state.
